# GWT source map in webworker

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, web-worker, source-maps

I run js compiled with GWT in webworker. Unfortunately, source maps don't work, at least in Chrome. Did anybody had this problem? What might it be? Does Chrome support source map for workers?

Comment: Sourcemaps work in chrome, I use them every day. I don't understand, why sources in webworkers should be different from other sources. The sourcemap mechanism will provide all sources from the client to the server. How do you implement the webworker code that it does not appear in the sourcetree on the client?

Comment: @thst They do work in Chrome, but work only for web stuff not workers stuff.

Comment: Sorry for not helping, but keeping asking. I find this issue interesting as we spent days already in figuring source not refreshong stuff. If this has a solution, I am interested :-) Is this a GWT issue at all then? I have not used the webworkers yet, but as you describe the issue, the sourcemap is not provided by the sdm server, but I can hardl believe that, so couldn't it be that the webworker thread in chrome does not ask for them? They are not in the sourcemaps listing/tree in the debugger of chrome?